# Field validation based on previous field's value in Google forms

Tags: forms, validation, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

In a Google Form, how can I limit a field's input range to be equal to or less than the inputted value of a previous field?

ie: Question 1. How many employees do you have?
    Question 2. How many are full time?

As it seems to me, there is a way to implement scripts, but I have yet to find someone who has written one for this case...

Answer (score 1):

First, Apps Script can't add validations to a Google Form. Not "as the user type" or when they click "Submit" (or continue). The only thing you can do on Apps Script is to analyze the answers **after** the user sends it, and then discard/ignore it if it fails some criteria you have. You may send an email to user (if you're collecting it on your form), informing that his answers are invalid, etc. But you can't prevent them from submitting bad answers.

Second, Google Forms does not have this type of validation itself either.

So, the only real solution for having these type of validations (preventing bad answers of being sent) is to not use Google Forms but something else. A custom Apps Script web app or a regular form you might build with another tool. I've seen some people copying the resulting html of a Google Form and hosting it themselves so they can add such tweaks. You may search and find a somewhat automated solution for you. If not, you'll have to develop this yourself or hire someone to.